# how to rotate an UIImageview under the finger with constant 5 degrees rotation?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, touch, image-rotation, touchesmoved

I am making a clock that can be controlled by the user.I have a UIImagview with a name **minhandview**(minute hand needle of the clock). I want to rotate it under my finger(it should track the finger movement) with a **constant rotation of 5 degrees** when the user keep on rotating it.I am using the following code for it

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)_touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)_event
```

{

```
UITouch *touch=[[_event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if([touch view]==minhandview)
{

    minhandview.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(minhandview.transform, Degrees2Radians(5));
}
```

}

the image is rotating fine 5 degrees everytime this method is called but it is not following my finger(rotating to fast) how can I correct it? Please help. thanks

Comment: still waiting for answer anyone help me please

Comment: Who are you? What did you know?